# Ldap authentication in apache linux

Tags: linux, apache, ldap, windows-authentication, autologin

I am doing SSO integration in my project. Where my PHP application is hosted in linux environment with Apache server. I am currently trying to implement LDAP module and getting success when entered username and password.

But I need to know how I can implement autologin function if my website application client is using Windows OS and IE or other supporting browsers.

Kindly advice. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

For doing the LDAP implementation you can use the php ldap library
http://php.net/ldap , I use it for my projects, but sometimes is a little tricky.

In the other hand, in able to do an autologin, the browser is the one that must pass the login information to your page(php) to be able to perform some kind of authentication. So to be honest, autologin is not possible it will be a very bad security risk to be able to get user credentials via a browser.

Comment: Hi Vidal, It may seems to be bad to pass information through browser. But in case using our application in intranet, we need user logged in information like username and firstname etc. So php ldap is good to check login. But it does not provide information for autologging users.

Comment: My friend what I am saying is that auto login is not possible, if you want to implement autologin you will need to have someking of application in the user computer that create that session in the web for you, then when the users visit the page he will be login, because we created a session beforehand. The challenge... create the session from the pc and get the correct credentials.